# Softlayer - Running Jumpgate

Tags: python, openstack, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Fist question, somebody knows if the Jumpgate project still active? I see that the last activity was in 2014.

Second,
I tried to install Jumpgate using the steps in this article [http://bodenr.blogspot.jp/2014/03/managing-openstack-softlayer-resources.html] however when running the following line

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

An error is generated

> error: Installed distribution pbr 0.11.1 conflicts with requirement pbr>=1.6

I think the problem is because the version of the packages referenced have changed.

Does somebody knows how to install jumpgate successfully with the current (2016/08) python packages ?

This is the list of my python packages:

```
Babel (2.3.4)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
click (6.6)
configobj (4.7.2)
Cython (0.24.1)
debtcollector (1.8.0)
decorator (3.4.0)
falcon (0.1.8)
funcsigs (1.0.2)
gunicorn (18.0)
iniparse (0.4)
iso8601 (0.1.11)
jumpgate (0.1)
keystoneauth1 (2.11.1)
monotonic (1.2)
msgpack-python (0.4.8)
netaddr (0.7.18)
netifaces (0.10.4)
oslo.config (1.5.0)
oslo.i18n (3.8.0)
oslo.serialization (2.13.0)
oslo.utils (3.16.0)
pbr (0.11.1)
perf (0.1)
pip (8.1.2)
positional (1.1.1)
prettytable (0.7.2)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.6)
py2-ipaddress (3.4.1)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycurl (7.19.0)
Pygments (2.1.3)
pygobject (3.14.0)
pygpgme (0.3)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
pyparsing (2.1.8)
python-mimeparse (1.5.2)
python-novaclient (5.0.1.dev33)
pytz (2016.6.1)
pyudev (0.15)
pyxattr (0.5.1)
requests (2.11.1)
rfc3986 (0.3.1)
setuptools (0.9.8)
simplejson (3.8.2)
six (1.10.0)
slip (0.4.0)
slip.dbus (0.4.0)
SoftLayer (5.1.0)
stevedore (1.17.0)
urlgrabber (3.10)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
wheel (0.29.0)
wrapt (1.10.8)
yum-metadata-parser (1.1.4)
```

Thank you

--

Let me update the question:

After installing the dependencies

```
cd /usr/local/jumpgate && sudo pip install -r tools/requirements.txt
```

I had to rollback oslo.config and falcon to previous version

```
sudo pip install -U oslo.config==1.5.0
sudo pip install -U falcon==0.1.8
```

Now I'm able to install Jumpgate and run it.

```
gunicorn "jumpgate.wsgi:make_api()" --bind="localhost:5000" --timeout=600 --access-logfile="-" -w 4
```

Continuing with the @bolden Blog I installed nova client OpenStack and configure the global variables to match SoftLayer account

```
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0
export OS_PASSWORD=xyz
export OS_TENANT_ID=SL9999999
export OS_USERNAME=SoftLayerUserName
```

Next I tried to execute the test

```
nova --debug  availability-zone-list
```

And I get the following error:

**Server side:**

REQ: GET /v2.0  {} [ReqId: req-9b0e1fe0-6536-11e6-818f-525400b263eb] 
UNKNOWN PATH: GET /v2.0
RESP: GET /v2.0  501 Not Implemented [ReqId: req-9b0e1fe0-6536-11e6-818f-525400b263eb]

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2016:20:26:28 +0900] "GET /v2.0 HTTP/1.1" 501 95 "-" "nova keystoneauth1/2.11.1 python-requests/2.9.1 CPython/2.7.5"
REQ: POST /v2.0/tokens  {} [ReqId: req-9b0f926c-6536-11e6-818f-525400b263eb]
RESP: POST /v2.0/tokens  401 Unauthorized [ReqId: req-9b0f926c-6536-11e6-818f-525400b263eb]

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2016:20:26:29 +0900] "POST /v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1" 401 100 "-" "nova keystoneauth1/2.11.1 python-requests/2.9.1 CPython/2.7.5"

**Nova**

DEBUG (session:337) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http:// 127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: nova keystoneauth1/2.11.1 python-requests/2.9.1 CPython/2.7.5"

INFO (connectionpool:207) Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1

DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "GET /v2.0 HTTP/1.1" 501 95

DEBUG (session:366) RESP: [501] content-length: 95 x-compute-request-id: req-9b0e1fe0-6536-11e6-818f-525400b263eb Server: gunicorn/19.6.0 Connection: close Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 11:26:28 GMT content-type: application/json
RESP BODY: {"notImplemented": {"message": "Not Implemented", "code": "501", "details": "Not Implemented"}}

DEBUG (session:569) Request returned failure status: 501

WARNING (base:122) Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.

DEBUG (v2:63) Making authentication request to http ://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens

INFO (connectionpool:242) Resetting dropped connection: 127.0.0.1

DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "POST /v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1" 401 100

DEBUG (session:569) Request returned failure status: 401

DEBUG (shell:984) Unauthorized (HTTP 401)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/shell.py", line 982, in main
    OpenStackComputeShell().main(argv)
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 570, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
Unauthorized: Unauthorized (HTTP 401)
ERROR (Unauthorized): Unauthorized (HTTP 401)

My questions:

1 - Is the Unauthorized message comming from SoftLayer or from Jumpgate ?

2 - Is the default SoftLayer end point valid? [/etc/jumpgate/jumpgate.conf]

```
endpoint = https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3/
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've never installed jumpgate before, but I was able to install it.

At firts I got a similar error like you got, but I fix it installing all the needed pakages using pip.

```
sudo pip install falcon
sudo pip install requests
sudo pip install six
sudo pip install oslo.config
sudo pip install softlayer
sudo pip install pycrypto
sudo pip install iso8601
```

and then I ran:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

And it installed successfully.

The list of packages installed are:

```
falcon (1.0.0)
requests (2.9.1)
six (1.10.0)
oslo.config (3.15.0)
softlayer (4.1.1)
pycrypto (2.4.1)
iso8601 (0.1.11)
```

I hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However, are you able to run it ? With those packages, when executing gunicorn it will show an error loading oslo.config. So my solution was to rollback oslo.config to version 1.5.0 and falcon to version 0.1.8

Comment: Nope I did not use, I do now how to do it sorry, maybe you can upload the issue in the git project for more help

Answer (score 0):

Run all in a virtualenv and save yourself some headaches.